# @UiThread pre/post Execute

Tags: android-annotations

With android-annotations I can replace `AsyncTask<Param, Progress, Result>` with `@UiThread`.

But is possible to handle something like onPreExcecute / onPostExecute of AsynkTask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no callback methods to handle this. But you can have the same result by calling methods at the beginning and at the end of your `@Background` annotated method (you said `@UIThread` but I hope this was a mistake :)).

Example :

```
@Background
void longRunningProcess() {
    longRunningProcessStarted();
    //...
    longRunningProcessEnded();
}

@UiThread
void longRunningProcessStarted() {

}

@UiThread
void longRunningProcessEnded() {

}
```

We also [wrote a cookbook](https://github.com/DayS/androidannotations/wiki/Publish%20Progress) about this.

Comment: I have read better your answer.. but why you say UiThread is a mistake? I have anotated a method with UiThread and this method create an excel file. I want to display a ProgressDialog that can cancel the operation in progress.

Comment: It's a mistake because you shouldn't execute long-running process in UIThread, like file creation.

Comment: Ok! One last thing.. in order to kill the background service the only way is to search for the service by name and than kill it.. i have no way to keep an instance of it in the creating view? Thank you

Comment: IF you want to cancel a background task (ie a `@Background` annotated method), the soon-to-be-release 3.0 version of AA will handle this use case. If you want to stop an Android service, you could just use the IntentBuilder in 3.0: `MyService_.intent(context).stop()` or before this version `context.stopService(MyService_.intent(context).get())`